# Multiple organization in a salesforce

Tags: community, developer-edition, multi-org

in a salesforce we can have multi-organization. But is it possible if the data from one organization to another organization is private? This means in a salesforce, we have org from Iran and Japan, but both countries cannot access each other data. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: I assume you're using "org" to refer to a department or business unit within your company? Have you completed the [Data Security](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/data_security) module in Trailhead to understand the architecture of Salesforce data security?

Comment: Org here I refer to a business unit within the company

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. In fact, it has been done, from two separate "sister" companies that needed complete isolation to financial firms that required dozens of individual "orgs" within their main org in terms of data isolation. Not all of these features are available out of the box, but Sales and Support can offer you product options and additional features to fully support this endeavor, if you want to go this route.

Comment: Thank you sir!.